# How to reset css in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

I'm developing an angular project but I ran into a problem, I want to achieve the following. 1. click a button and open a new window.  2. I don't want the css rules applied to the whole application to have any effect on the pop up new window.

Here's what I have tried.

.ts file

```
goToLink(url: string){
  window.open(url,'',  'scrollbars=yes,width=300, height=300');
}
```

.html file

```
<a (click)="goToLink('filter');" >Filter</a>
```

I want a new look/css in the filter without entire page of the website css

Comment: put CSS in the component - that way only the component is affected; if you want the whole app to be styled and just ignore one component, then you can use a different class inside that component so that the effect is not applied to it;

Comment: @AkberIqbal I pasted the css inside the filter component and the results seems the same nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

Make a filter component and write its own css. Try not to use any class in the HTML that you have defined globally. This is called ShadowDom